# java-test case for javamail

Tags: java, email, junit4

Here is the code for sending email:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
String host = "XXXXXX";
String from = "XXXXXX";
String to = "XXXXXX";

String content = "xxxxxxxx";
String subject = "xxxxxxxx";
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, null);
Mailbox mailbox = Mailbox.get(to);
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

message.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setText(content);
session.setDebug(true);

Transport.send(message);
```

Now I would like to know how to retrieve the emails from a gmail account and be able to read them? I also want to know how to test whether my email is sent successfully or not?

Here is the debug content:
     '

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.3.1
     DEBUG: getProvider() returning            javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
    DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
    DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "XXXX", port 25

    220 XXXXX ESMTP Symantec Messaging Gateway
    DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "XXXXX", port: 25

    EHLO XXXXX
    250-XXXXX says EHLO to XXXXX
    250-STARTTLS
    250-8BITMIME
    250-SIZE 262144000
    250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
    250 PIPELINING
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "262144000"
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
    DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
    MAIL FROM:<xxxxxx>
    250 2.0.0 MAIL FROM accepted
    RCPT TO:<xxxxxxx>
    250 2.0.0 RCPT TO accepted
    DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
    DEBUG SMTP:   xxxxxx
    DATA
    354 3.0.0 continue.  finished with "\r\n.\r\n"
    Message-ID: <942986815.1484331504128.JavaMail.XXXXXX>
    From: xxxxxx
    To: xxxxxxx
    Subject: xxxxxxx
    Mime-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

    xxxxxxx
    .
    250 2.0.0 OK 91/8D-04168-0F919785
    QUIT
```

'

Comment: It should through an error if it fails to send, so just wrap it in a try and catch statement

Comment: It is sent successfully. I need to retrieve it from using session.getStore(); but how to retrieve store object for smtp host.

Comment: In other words you want code to read emails from an inbox?

Comment: Yes, I need code for reading emails. javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc] is present as provider. How to connect to imap or pop3 with above code unchanged, as I am using smtp host is it possible to connect to imap or pop3 store and get the messages in INBOX

Comment: Ok, I posted the proper code to retrieve emails from a gmail account in java

Comment: Do I need to change any setting in POP/IMAP download in gmail settings and any jars related to pop3 or go with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class that defines a fetch method to retrieve emails from a gmail inbox.

The following two libraries must be added for the code to compile.

1- the java activation library which can be downloaded from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-135046.html

2- The java mail library which can be downloaded from here https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home

---

```
  import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.DataOutputStream;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileOutputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.util.Date;
  import java.util.Properties;

  import javax.mail.Address;
  import javax.mail.Folder;
  import javax.mail.Message;
  import javax.mail.MessagingException;
  import javax.mail.Multipart;
  import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
  import javax.mail.Part;
  import javax.mail.Session;
  import javax.mail.Store;

  public class FetchingEmail {

  public static void fetch(String pop3Host, String storeType, String user,
  String password) {
  try {
     // create properties field
     Properties properties = new Properties();
     properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
     properties.put("mail.pop3.host", pop3Host);
     properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
     properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
     Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
     // emailSession.setDebug(true);

     // create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
     Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

     store.connect(pop3Host, user, password);

     // create the folder object and open it
     Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
     emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

     // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
     Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
     System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

     for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        Message message = messages[i];
       //now over here you can process the message object in any way you like
     }

     // close the store and folder objects
     emailFolder.close(false);
     store.close();

  } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (MessagingException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Now that you have this class - add code in the for loop to process each message in the way that you would like. Then call the fetch method as follows `fetch("pop.gmail.com", "pop3", username, password);`

Comment: I am not getting messages. Do I need any further changes in settings of my gmail account?

Comment: Yes, you need to enable pop in gmail settings